# How does the industry refer to storing mulitple boolean value state in one integer?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

Here is an easy question.

How does the industry refer to storing mulitple boolean value state in one integer?

The SetWindowPos api is an example.

```
SWP_NOSIZE         DEFINE 1
SWP_NOMOVE         DEFINE 2
SWP_NOZORDER       DEFINE 4
SWP_NOREDRAW       DEFINE 8
SWP_NOACTIVATE     DEFINE 16
```

If the integer is 11 then 1, 2 and 8 (`SWP_NOSIZE`, `SWP_NOMOVE` and `SWP_NOREDRAW`) are on.

What is the buzz word for this pattern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

Answer (score 7):

I have always called this "bit flags", since they are flags, and there is one flag per bit. This seems fairly standard, though I can't guarantee how standard...

Comment: This is my preferred for the general case. "Bitfield" should only be used when the bits fit in a machine word (otherwise you have a "bit array").

Comment: fields is better because sometimes you pair up bits to hold 3-state and 4-state data (and larger combinations).

Answer (score 3):

[**bitset** or **bit array**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "flags" too.  This term is used consistently in many places where powers of 2 are ORed (to give one example, System.Reflection.BindingFlags in .NET, and there are many others).

The term "bit field" has a specific meaning, e.g. bit fields in C structs - but there is no such struct in the above example; the programmer chose to use an integer instead.